# Matching an individual character against a list of characters

Tags: php

I would like to know how to see if an individual character that i have pulled out of a string matches any of a list of characters, i know i could do this through iteration but i would prefer not to. I also need to be able to find

I am currently trying to do this with `preg_match()` but it does not seem to be giving me the results i need
my current code:

```
const CHAR_LIST = '[abcdefghij+-/*&^]'; 
$start = //an arbitrary index that is after a character in the list
while(!(preg_match($this::CHAR_LIST, $expression[$start]) === 1))
{
    $start--;
}
//after loop $start should be indexed to the character in the list
```

note: i need to find the closest preceeding and closest anteceeding special character to the arbitrary index that i started with.

**UPDATE**
I changed my implementation to use strpos and strrpos, but my code still doesn't work, can strrpos handle symbols as characters? Updated code follows:

```
const CHAR_LIST = '+-*/^rabcdefg';
$index = 5;//arbitrary point between where the symbols are
$start = strrpos(substr($expression,0,index-1),$this::CHAR_LIST);
$end = strpos(substr($expression,index+1),$this::CHAR_LIST);
```

index is one of the characters in the list which is why the strpos and strrpos go over it.

Comment: For those who care I ended up using `strcspn()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)?

```
strrpos — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a regex character class for the match:

```
while(!(preg_match("/[".$this::CHAR_LIST."]/", $expression[$start]) === 1))
{
    $start--;
}
```

The square brackets "[]" represent a character class.

Comment: If `CHAR_LIST` is an array, you might need to use `implode($this::CHAR_LIST)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions isn't the way to go here. Use strrpos. strrpos would work faster than pattern matching using regex.